# array multidimensional primes check

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, primes

I've searched, and I found nothing about what I am going to ask. I have a question as a beginner and a student who learns JavaScript. I know how to check if a number is a prime or not. This is my problem:

```
numbers([
  [5, 7, 10],
  [8, 2, 3],
  [44, 50, 22]
])

expected output:
[
  ['#', '#', 10],
  [8, '#', '#'],
  [44, 50, 22]
]
```

What I need is: if there is a prime number in a multidimensional array, i need to change it to `#`, and if not, nothing change. This task requires no built in function such as `.indexOf`, `.include`, `.findIndex`, `.reduce`, `.map`, `.filter`, and no new parameters added, or regex. And this is what I got so far:

```
function multidimensionalPrimesChecker(numbers)
{
    for (var i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0 ; j < numbers[i].length ; j++)
        {
            if (numbers[i][j] % i === 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have no idea anymore how to solve this. Help me, please.
And thanks for your kindness

Comment: Why do you exactly perform the `module` operation using `i`? What do you expect to accomplish doing it?

Comment: You can use `array.map()` for this. If true, return the number, if false, return a `#`.

Comment: I imagine that he can't use this built in functions, since he specifically said "This task requires no built in function such as... map..."

Comment: yes, my lecture said that we don't need to use built in function because he wants us to understand the logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you will need a function to check if a number is prime or not, since your current check `numbers[i][j] % i === 0` only checks if `numbers[i][j]` is divisible by `i`. The next method will do it:

```
function isPrime(num)
{
    for(let i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++)
        if(num % i === 0) return false;

    return num !== 1 && num !== 0;
}
```

Now, using your code, you detect this condition and replace by `#` when the condition becomes true.

```js
const input = [
    [5, 7, 10],
    [8, 2, 3],
    [44, 50, 22]
];

function isPrime(num)
{
    for(let i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++)
        if(num % i === 0) return false;

    return num !== 1 && num !== 0;
}

function multidimensionalPrimesChecker(numbers)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (isPrime(numbers[i][j]))
                numbers[i][j] = "#";
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}

let res = multidimensionalPrimesChecker(input);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: thanks, it works. and thanks again for your explanation.